# What are the forces acting on a rectangular polymer film submerged in a turbulent flow (stirred tank)?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, turbulence

I am new to research in fluid mechanics and for one of my experiments, I'd like your help.

I need to write a force balance on a polymer film in a cylindrical tank at a fixed position.

The film moves back and forth in the z-direction, depending on the turbulent flow around. It is fixed by a clamp that is mounted on the table.

[image: Sketch]

I have tried to look for objects in unsteady flow but the way my film is placed, I do not know what type of object to consider (submerged? moving body?).

Any help is appreciated, thanks a lot!!